# Using .Net Core on Linux with Linux Drivers

Tags: c#, ubuntu, drivers

I have been having ongoing issues obtaining data from a remote server operated by another company. There seems to be an issue with their windows drivers which results in caching issues and missed data.

They have supplied us Linux drivers that apparently do not have this same issue. My problem is everything I have written is in C#. So I was hoping to install the .NET Core on Ubuntu, and run the C# code, but using the Linux drivers. I am new to all of this and am unsure whether this would work - or would using the .Net core interfere with the linux drivers somehow?

Comment: There would be no magic. Start learning from https://docs.asp.net.